# Using NavDeepLinkBuilder: notification to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like to improve my code with function:
-> after clicking a notification it goes to direct fragment

I basically use navigation component to navigate through fragments. As well it is able to go to the first page on my activity after clicking a notification, only when My application is closed from the background.
Application is one activity with many fragments.

When my application is on some other fragments it crashes.

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination com.example.program:id/action_global_MyGoalFragment cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(com.example.program:id/nav_main_graph) startDestination={NavDestination(com.example.program:id/MyGoalFragment) label=MyGoalFragment}
```

That's my code:

```
        val pendingIntent2 = NavDeepLinkBuilder(applicationContext)
            .setComponentName(MainActivity::class.java)
            .setGraph(R.navigation.nav_main_graph)
            .setDestination(R.id.action_global_MyGoalFragment)
            .createPendingIntent()
```

EDIT:
I have found the method that someone used.. I understand that setArguments(bundle) could be used to send some data from fragment to another, like position of the list etc.

[NavDeepLinkBuilder pending intent dosent work when app in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65110899/navdeeplinkbuilder-pending-intent-dosent-work-when-app-in-background?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Do you know how to solve my issue?

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue. I have a single-activity app with couple of fragments. You can try to set in setDestination your fragment id not an anction id

```
.setDestination(R.id.your_fragment_id_in_nav_graph)
```